# SQL queries for calculating shipping charges based on subtotal amount

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

| ID | Name | min_amount | charge |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Standard | 50.00 | 3.00 |
| 2 | Express | 50.00 | 5.00 |
| 3 | Standard | 100.00 | 2.00 |
| 4 | Express | 100.00 | 0.00 |

so I have this table in SQL and my requirement is to calculate shipping based on min_amount (subtotal). for eg: if the subtotal is 45.00 I want to get the row with ID 1,2 (because 45.00 < 50.00). and similarly if subtotal is 55 it should be the row with ID 3,4.

```
SELECT id,min_amount, MAX(charge) as shipping FROM `shippings` WHERE min_amount > 45.00 GROUP BY name
```

**this is working.** but when the value changes to 101.00, this returns nothing I want it to return the max min_amount row which is 3,4

what should I change? and what is the eloquent query for this, since I'm using laravel but can be done without it.

Comment: There is not mention of the column subtotal in your schema or your query, how is this related?

Comment: sorry for that mistake, i edited the que

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the highest min amount value first and use it to make a decision on upper value using `IF` condition in `WHERE` clause,

```
SELECT id, name, min_amount, MAX(charge) as shipping
FROM shippings,
     (SELECT MAX(min_amount) as min_amount_limit FROM shippings) z
WHERE min_amount >= IF(z.min_amount_limit < 101.00, z.min_amount_limit, 101.00)
GROUP BY name;
```

[Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5fe074a/22)